# Running 2 suites of junit tests with different @before setup

Tags: java, junit

I have a bunch of test classes that require the same database setup. Originally, I use @BeforeClass annotation in each of theses test classes to run this setup. To run all these tests, I use a test suite class, i.e. one with the @RunWith(Suite.class) annotation.

Next, I want to run these same tests in another enviornment as well, which requires a different database setup. Ideally, if the test suite recognizes @before annotation, I can move the setup out of the test classes and into the test suite. But that's not the case. So now I am thinking about calling each setup and then each test class using the JUnitCore api. I am wondering is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Any reason for not using a config file and put there enviornment info?

Comment: By different database setup, I mean I actually populate the data in a different way programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

**Ideally, if the test suite recognizes @before annotation, I can move the setup out of the test classes and into the test suite.**

`Suite`s do recognized `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass` so you can put all your initialization inside the Suite class as static methods annotated with `@BeforeClass` and `@AfterClass`

Comment: It recognizes BeforeClass but not Before, which is what I need in order to run the setup for each test class, not just once before any test class is run.